# Python: How to replace array with discretized (binned) values, not the bin numbers?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

Suppose I have an array `np.array([1,2,4,8,12,16,20,48])`. I want to replace the values by the nearest quantiles. So for example, the quartiles (0%,25%, 50%, 75%) are `[1,3.5,10,15.6]`. I want to bin the array values by the quartile values and then replace the array values by the quartile bin values to which they belong. In the result of `np.digitize` is `[0,0,1,1,2,3,3]`. I want to then replace the array as `[1,1,3.5,3.5,10,10,15.6,15.6]`

The thing is, I have HUGE arrays and so I **can't** spend the time with a for-style loop to replace the values one at a time, such as:

```
data=np.array([1,2,4,8,12,16,20,48])
bins=[1,3.5,10,15.6]
newdata=[bins[_] for _ in np.digitize(data,bins[1:])]
```

Anyone know of a clever way to do this?

EDIT and SOLUTION: change the above to:

```
bins=np.array([1,3.5,10,15.6]
newdata=bins[np.digitize(data,bins[1:])]
```

Comment: Do you mean like `bins = np.array([1,3.5,10,15.6])` and then `newdata=bins[np.digitize(data,bins[1:])]`?

Answer (score 2):

Just use the fact that if you index a numpy array with a list/array of indices you get the values at those indices:

```
data = np.array([1,2,4,8,12,16,20,48])
bins = np.array([1,3.5,10,15.6])

dig = np.digitize(data, bins) - 1 # -1 because digitize returns the index of where it is larger than the value in bins
newdata = bins[dig]
# array([ 1. ,  1. ,  3.5,  3.5, 10. , 15.6, 15.6, 15.6])
```

Instead of the `-1` you could also digitize with `bins[1:]` as [@jdehesa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1782792/jdehesa) suggested [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49072378/python-how-to-replace-array-with-discretized-binned-values-not-the-bin-numbe/49072512#comment85150663_49072378).

You need to ensure that `bins` is a `np.array` as in the example above, because indexing lists this way is not possible.

Comment: @AstroBen Please edit your question if you have more details. The code as written here works on my machine. Maybe `bins` is a `list` and not a `np.array` in your code?

Comment: I tried that first, before posting. I get a traceback:

`    bins[dig]`

`    TypeErrorTraceback (most recent call last)`
`    <ipython-input-1037-fa1ce02e82f4> in <module>()`
`    ----> 1 bins[dig]`

`    TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index`

Comment: @AstroBen That is definitely because you did not turn `bins` into a `np.array` (was stuck on that for a bit while writing the answer, actually).

Comment: Thanks!!! That did it! I posted that as an edit to the original. Gosh I'm frustrated I missed that.